# Getting CORS error while accessing audio files on same server in chrome

Tags: nginx, cors, chrome, ajax, audio

Access to video at '/path/to/mp3/file' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request had a target IP address space of `unknown` yet the resource is in address space `public`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet discovered why this CORS error occurs but what I can assure you is that it is in the http/2 protocol in http/1.1 it works normally, a lot of people are experiencing this after the latest security policy updates of browsers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can check this link, it was a chrome bug that was recently fixed in version 103

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1332943#makechanges